# compiler showing different errors for unassigned struct object field and property

Tags: c#, properties, data-members

In the below code in line:1, the compiler shows error :"Use of possibly unassigned field 'IntField' " but for line: 2 the error is "Use of possibly unassigned local variable 'structObj' " . Why different error?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StructA structObj;

        Console.WriteLine(structObj.IntField); //Line :1
        Console.WriteLine(structObj.IntProperty); //Line :2            

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


struct StructA
{
    public int IntField;
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize the object StructA structObj = new StructA(); As for the why's of the errors, I'm sure someone will explain that better than I would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `StructA` is a struct and `IntField` is a field.

Try `StructA structObj = new StructA()` before you use it.

I think the reason of the difference between the errors is that the property is converted to methods. And calling a method on a not initialize object is not possible.

Comment: After reading your answer i got another doubt ie if properties are converted to methods? So i googled it and msdn has cleared my doubt. It says "Properties are actually special methods called accessors.". So i guess answer is the correct reason why compiler shows two different errors. Thanks Jeroen.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to call new() for structure because if the New operator is not used, the fields remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all the fields are initialized.

so for intialization of value for property it must be

```
StructA structObj = new StructA();
```

You can try without use of new for only variable in structure but initialization is required so just assign value like

```
structObj.IntField= 1;
```

But for property you required new().